# i want to find the avg of stayedtime from group of mongo documents in rails

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, aggregation-framework

```
UserStayedTime.collection.aggregate( 
    { "$match" => {
       "starttime"=> { 
           "$gte" => start_date.to_time.utc.beginning_of_day
       },
       "endtime" => {
           "$lte" => end_date.to_time.utc.end_of_day
       }
    }}, 
    { "$project"=> { 
        "y" => {"$year"=>"$starttime"},
        "m"=> {"$month"=>"$starttime"},
        "d"=> {"$dayOfMonth"=>"$starttime"},
        "h"=> {"$hour"=>"$starttime"}
    }}, 
    { "$group"=> {
        "_id"=> { 
            "year"=>"$y",
            "month"=>"$m",
            "day"=>"$d",
            "hour"=>"$h"
        }, 
        :count=> { "$sum"=> 1}, 
        "avg"=> { "$avg" => "$stayedtime" }
    }}
)
```

Output is

```
=> [
    {
        "_id"=> {
            "year"=>2014, 
            "month"=>6,
            "day"=>24,
            "hour"=>12
        }, 
        "count"=>12,
        "avg"=>0.0
    }
]
```

But it's wrong in my database I have 12 records with stayedtime=30
but am getting wrong output, I mean stayedtime should not be 0.0.

Please anyone help me

Comment: You don't define `$stayedtime`.

Comment: where i can define $stayedtime

Answer (score 1):

You introduced the problem in your [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) where you omitted fields for the document. Best to just do what you wanted there in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
UserStayedTime.collection.aggregate( 
    { "$match" => {
       "starttime"=> { 
           "$gte" => start_date.to_time.utc.beginning_of_day
       },
       "endtime" => {
           "$lte" => end_date.to_time.utc.end_of_day
       }
    }}, 
    { "$group"=> {
        "_id"=> { 
            "year"=> {"$year"=>"$starttime"},
            "month"=> {"$month"=>"$starttime"},
            "day"=> {"$dayOfMonth"=>"$starttime"},
            "hour"=> {"$hour"=>"$starttime"}
        }, 
        :count=> { "$sum"=> 1}, 
        "avg"=> { "$avg" => "$stayedtime" }
    }}
)
```

So you really don't need that stage to be separate, it's faster this way and avoids pitfalls like omitting fields.

Comment: @Shekar No problem. Bit of advice when learning how to do it. A bit more advice, click accept on the answers that help you on here as I notice you have not accepted any of your answers to date.